# How do I use Legacy OpenGL calls with QT6?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt6

I'm new to Qt and am trying to import some older C++ openGL code. I'm currently using Qt 6.4. I've subclassed my OpenGL-using class to `QOpenGlFunctions`.

Many of the `glFoo` calls "work" but the class also uses calls like `glEnableClientState`, `glVertexPointer`, `glNormalPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer`, `glDisableClientState`, `glColor4fv`, & `glMaterialfv` which come up with errors like `undefined reference to __imp_glTextCoordPointer`. Looking at the documentation these appear to no long be supported by "default" but it looks like they are supported using older versions of `QOpenGlFunctions` such as `QOpenGlFunction_1_4` (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qopenglfunctions-1-4.html).

Trying to change my subclass from `QOpenGLFunctions` to `QOpenGLFunctions_1_4` complains that really only `QOpenGLFunctions_1_4_CoreBackend` and `QOpenGLFunctions_1_4_DeprecatedBackend` exist but there appears to be no documentation on those and if I subclass to one of them I start seeing complaints about my constructor...

How do I actually access the functions from these older versions of the class?

Comment: Did you include the header file?

Comment: Including an OpenGL header shouldn't be needed if QOpenGLFunctions is being subclassed. Are you calling `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` in `initializeGL()`? Have you tried subclassing from a compatibility profile, e.g. `QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Compatibility`? (Note that Apple doesn't support compatibility profiles)

Comment: If you're using a .pro file, are you adding `QT += openglwidgets`?

Comment: I am include the headers required to implement the most "modern" Qt-take on OpenGL.  But it doesn't have access to some of the older functions that are no deprecated.




I did try subclassing to a compatibility profile, but it wasn't working and, apparently, that's not "how it's done"

Apparently the way to access an old OpenGL profile is like this:

QOpenGLFunctions_1_4* funcs = QOpenGLVersionFunctionsFactory::get<QOpenGLFunctions_1_4>(context());
funcs->glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

See my other Answer for more details.




I am using cmake but I did the equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by [Chris Kawa](https://forum.qt.io/user/chris-kawa) over at the [Qt Forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/140469/using-legacy-opengl-calls-with-qt6/6) and it worked for me!  Here is his answer:

*OpenGL 3.1 introduced profiles. Core profile does not support these old functions and Compatibility profile does.
So first you have to make sure you have a context in version either lower than 3.1 (which does not support profiles) or 3.1 and up set up to use Compatibility profile. AFAIK Qt does not support OpenGL < 3.1 anymore, so you only have the latter option.
If you're not sure what context you have you can simply do qDebug() << your_context and it will print out all the parameters, or you can query individual fields of it e.g. your_conext->format()->profile(). If your context is not set correctly the simplest way is to set it up like this before any OpenGL is initialized in your app:*

```
QSurfaceFormat fmt;
fmt.setVersion(3,1);
fmt.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
fmt.setOptions(QSurfaceFormat::DeprecatedFunctions);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);
```

*When you have the correct context you can access the deprecated functions like this:*

```
QOpenGLFunctions_1_4* funcs = QOpenGLVersionFunctionsFactory::get<QOpenGLFunctions_1_4>(context());
if(funcs)
{
    //do OpenGL 1.4. stuff, for example
    funcs->glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
else
{
    // Not a valid context?
}
```

And for anyone as amateur as I am, `context()` comes from `QOpenGLWidget::context()` which returns a `QOpenGLContext*`